# React JS, stop errors displaying in production

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, error-handling

So recently we launched our first React JS application online. However, when people open the site, then move to a different tab and close their computer, an error message displays when they come back. Here is what they see(not this exact image but the same idea):

[image: React JS problem]

Once the user refreshes the page, it works perfectly again...

**I'm wondering 2 things:**

**1)** is there a way to hide these errors?

**2)** is there a good way to refresh the page when/if they appear?

Comment: You are using development build  that why it is showing the error page

Answer (score 3):

[image]

You are using development build. From [create-react-app docs](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app#quick-overview) (I assume it is create-react-app):

> When you’re ready to deploy to production, create a minified bundle
>   with `npm run build`.

However uncaught error will cause the whole tree to be unmounted so I suggest to use [componentDidCatch hook.](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidcatch)

Answer (score 0):

You should create an [error boundary](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html) one level above the `App` component and call it something like `Wrapper` below.

```js
class Wrapper extends React.Component {
  componentDidCatch(error, info) {
    // Do something useful with error like logging to error reporting system
    // then force reload (if that's what you want):
    window.location.reload(true);
  }
  render() {
    return (<App/>)
  }
}
```

Comment: How would this be applied to something like this (in my index.js file): ReactDOM.render(<BrowserRouter><App/></BrowserRouter>, document.getElementById('root'));